# Change blog link in election text to HTTPS

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, election, ssl

The introductory text for [elections](https://english.stackexchange.com/election/) contains the following paragraph with a link that's still HTTP:

> Community moderators are [accorded the highest level of privilege on our community](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), and should themselves be exemplars of positive behavior and leaders within the community.

Can this be changed to HTTPS, please?

These texts are stored as posts, of type 7 ('WikiPlaceholder') and can be edited by ♦ moderators, but it would be easier if this is done via the [mass update script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314169/295232).

Comment: Note: the mass update tool that we use only works on questions and answers. Would require additional work to extend it to work with other post types.

Comment: This only affects posts from old elections. I can confirm that our template text used here in new elections uses `https`.

Comment: Sure, but it's just a matter of changing the `PostTypeId`, I guess? It seems the text is reused from old elections (if there were any), cf. https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/9677/revisions

Comment: Isn't the linked election page for an ongoing election? Perhaps I'm not understanding what you meant by "old elections" vs. "new elections", @YaakovEllis... Could you clarify, please?

Comment: Clarification @TheAmplitwist: elections can inherit the template used in a previous election (which is the case in the one that was linked.

Comment: Ohh I see. Thanks @YaakovEllis :)

Comment: @Glorfindel Yeah that. And…making sure that they are being indexed properly in elastic, adding to the UI for running the dev route in question to allow selection of post types, testing it out, PR review, etc.