# Can I update a link in a post by another person if both old and new links were written by me?

Tags: discussion, edits, hyperlinks, broken-link

A page I wrote on a website I used to run has been edited in a way that makes it less useful.

I have a new website with a better version of this information.

If someone on Stack Exchange has linked to the old page (that I originally wrote), is it ok for me to edit their post in order to link to the new page (that I wrote) instead?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, of course. You don't need to provide [disclosure](/help/promotion) since you didn't add the initial link.

There are several initiatives around the network to restore broken links (e.g. via the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/), or with [mass updates by CMs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314169/295232)). This seems to be similar in spirit. Just make sure you don't bump too many posts at once (three per day is usually fine, when in doubt, ask on the site's own meta).