# Update Vue 2 links in all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, edits, hyperlinks

I'm trying to rewrite legacy Vue 2 links from https://vuejs.org/v2 to https://v2.vuejs.org/v2 across all Stack Exchange sites.

I've completed the update on Stack Overflow with a script, but [there are currently 228 of these posts on sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22%2Fvuejs.org%2Fv2%22) where I don't have edit privileges, including:

- [Portuguese Stack Overflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22%2Fvuejs.org%2Fv2%22)
- [Spanish Stack Overflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22%2Fvuejs.org%2Fv2%22)
- [Russian Stack Overflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22%2Fvuejs.org%2Fv2%22)
- [Magento Stack Exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22%2Fvuejs.org%2Fv2%22)

It turns out there's a [tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314169/161119) that can update these links in bulk. Can you please update the links for me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We've run our URL replacement tool across the network, all of these are now on https://v2.vuejs.org/v2. Please let us know if we missed anything :)

Comment: Thanks so much! The tool missed [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73276258/how-to-add-icon-beside-the-lable-using-vue-bootstrap/73280265#73280265) for some reason, but I've fixed that one manually.

Comment: @tony19 reason is the link is relative (`//vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html`) and the tool probably check only for absolute links.