# Bulk Fix possible for "Old New Thing" links? Important Win32 resource

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, hyperlinks, broken-link

I keep running into broken links to Raymond Chen's Old New Thing blog posts, which are a very valuable resource for winapi / win32 programmers.  There are probably close to a thousand of them site-wide on Stack Overflow and [several other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fblogs.msdn.microsoft.com%2Foldnewthing%2F%22&pagesize=50).

If an admin could do a bulk fix of the links in questions, answers, and comments it would upgrade the quality for many of them.

It's a simple replacement of the subdomain that Microsoft changed:

Old Old New Thing: `https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031111-00/?p=41883`

New Old New Thing: `https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031111-00/?p=41883`

If the Old Old became the New Old, the Stack Overflow world would be a better place.

Edit: see @wizzwizz4's answer for a list of the older link patterns.  The substitution above would fix the most recent of them but not the others.

Comment: To those voting to close this as "one site only", specific SO. This [network wide search query](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3a%22https%3a%2f%2fblogs.msdn.microsoft.com%2foldnewthing%2f%22&page=29) leads to results on at least 5 or 6 different network sites.

Comment: @Luuklag The OP initially focused mainly on SO. I have now edited the post to reflect that and retracted my close vote.

Comment: Sometimes the rest of us is forgotten. I'll go poke around a bit and see if a formal or informal approach might be better.

Comment: Are you sure the domain name is the only change?

Comment: @user3840170 - see wizzwizz4 answer below.  My suggestion would fix the most recent set of old links but not the older ones.

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft's moved The Old New Thing around quite a bit, and there are *lots* of different link formats:

- http://blogs.gotdotnet.com/raymondc/PermaLink.aspx/45113814-5b31-4f47-a1c5-6013350df2d2 ([9 results; not used for Old New Thing](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.gotdotnet.com%2F%22))
- http://weblogs.asp.net/oldnewthing/posts/44425.aspx

  - [http://weblogs.asp.net/oldnewthing/posts/43687.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20031226154106/http://weblogs.asp.net:80/oldnewthing/posts/43687.aspx) -> [http://weblogs.asp.net/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/15/43687.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20040327050658/http://weblogs.asp.net/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/15/43687.aspx)
- http://weblogs.asp.net/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/11/129759.aspx ([used *once*](https://superuser.com/a/1711486/541767), with an Internet Archive link)
- http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/11/56043.aspx ([used on Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.msdn.com%2Foldnewthing%22))
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031222-00/?p=41403

These formats are in approximate chronological order, except for blogs.gotdotnet.com. It's so rare I can't pin down when it comes from.

I've been trying to figure out how to fix these links for a while, mostly because there are links *on The Old New Thing* in all of these formats. The Internet Archive isn't entirely useful, here. I suspect it might take somebody in Microsoft to rewrite *all* of the links.

As a bonus, I wonder whether it's possible to rewrite comment links? Those are used quite a bit in The Old New Thing posts, some of which can become a *little* hard to follow now they've rotted. (I haven't checked whether they're used on Stack Exchange, because they're mostly anchor links, and I don't know how to search for those.)

Comment: Fixing the comment links would be very helpful for SO.  I've run into many answers where a comment from someone else points out an addition, warning, or correction using an Old New Thing link.  I hesitate to add the link to the answer since the answer often works as it is.

Comment: @DaveS Oh, good point – hadn't thought about links in Stack Exchange comments. I was thinking about links _to_ Old New Thing comments (as opposed to links to the posts themselves).

Comment: The last time Microsoft moved the domain they also deleted all comments older than X on purpose. Most of them can be found by finding the correct old url on archive.org except for a couple of years where Microsoft delay loaded the comments with JavaScript, those are lost forever :( And don't get me started on msdn > msdn2 > msdn > docs > learn.microsoft.com. And on top of this, Microsoft is deleting old KB articles on purpose!

Comment: There’s also a variant with `/b/oldnewthing/` in a pathname.

Comment: @user3840170 I couldn't place it in the chronology, so sort of gave up: do you have any idea where it goes?

Comment: Earliest Wayback Machine snapshot under `http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/` is from May 2010.

Answer (score 8):

I have a script which tries to repair [*all* broken MSDN blog links](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031111-00/?p=41883), including Raymond Chen's. Because the original URLs used to be quite different from the current ones, e.g. the article hosted at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/01/54734.aspx is now at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030901-00/?p=42723.

However, these newer (but still broken links) look much more like the right ones; it's simply a find `blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/` and replace with `devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/`. That makes it a candidate for the [automatic link replacement tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314169/295232), especially since we're talking about [almost 900 links](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22blogs.msdn.microsoft.com%2Foldnewthing%22) (and this trick may work for more than just the Old New Thing).